# move_base takes longer time to update the Goal Status why?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am doing an experiments on Navigation Stack by referring the Link ( http://wiki.ros.org/navigation  ) But While doing experiment I am facing one Issue.

I am using Rtabmap ( Localization ) + visual odometry + move_base ( with teb_local_planner ).

I am sending goal to the move_base by Cpp APIs, The myprogram.cpp( CPP code ) sends  5 goals to the robot one after the other but after reaching each goal the Robot waits for the GOAL STATUS for more than 2 minutes or it takes longer time than this .Please can you suggest me why the Status takes much longer time to update. Is their any parameter in move_base pkg or in the teb_local_planner which affect this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254066/move_base-takes-longer-time-to-update-the-goal-status-why-?/) by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2017-02-08**:
have you checked parameters `xy_goal_tolerance` and `yaw_goal_tolerance` in the teb_local_planner?

**Comment by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on 2017-02-08**:
Yes I have checked My Values are :
xy_goal_tolerance = 0.02
yaw_goal_tolerance = 0.08
Do this parameter have any relation with status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may have already found a solution to this problem, but I am currently doing the exact same thing, and I was encountering the exact same problem. I was also using the teb_local_planner, but it really didn't make sense that the local planner could be causing the waits. In the end I decided it was something in move_base, so I put together a very simplistic version of move_base where I monitor the global planner, local planner, and costmaps. This may not be the best answer for this problem as move_base has some nice features that I am missing, but I don't have it wait anymore when it reaches the waypoints and I also didn't need some of the other features in move_base as well. If you need some examples, look at [NavfnROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn) and [TrajectoryPlannerROS](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner). I only suggested these planners because  they have some examples of how to set it up, but you don't have to use those exact planners. You can use the global_planner and the teb_local_planner in a very similar way or even write your own.

---

Originally posted by [rittersb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44317/rittersb/) with karma: 16 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0